# How to add optional CA bundle in requests

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests

I need to access an API from python that does not serve the correct bundle when making TLS connection. I have found a [work-around](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification) which works, but I'd consider it unstable fix.

Assume api.example.org is the broken setup with cert from CA1, and www.example.org is a correct setup but has its certificate from CA2.

The following works

```
requests.get('https://api.example.org/', verify='/path/to/CA1_BUNDLE')
requests.get('https://www.example.org/')
```

But this doesnt work:-

```
requests.get('https://www.example.org/', verify='/path/to/CA1_BUNDLE')
```

Meaning if `verify='/path/to/CA1_BUNDLE'` is present, it only verifies against that particular CA and not any other thats installed in my system. If api.example.org fixes their crap, and gets certificate from different CA, then my code in production would stop working.

Is that a way to tell requests to use system certificates **as well as** `/path/to/CA1_BUNDLE` when doing the validation?

PS: Please do not advise me to use `verify=false`. This is 2016 and not 2008.

UPDATE: I no longer need a work-around, the site in question fixed their crap. However an elegant solution would still be appreciated for curiosity.

Comment: Add all your other (system) CAs to the bundle in /path/to/CA1_BUNDLE.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich: That makes maintenance a lot more work since currently my distro manages the system CAs for me.